# How to execute two EF linq query with one db round trip

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

when we work with ado.net then we can pass multiple sql separated by comma. here is one example.

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
connection.ConnectionString = connectionString; // put your connection string
command.CommandText = @"
     update table
     set somecol = somevalue;
     insert into someTable values(1,'test');";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Connection = connection;

try
{
    connection.Open();
}
finally
{
    command.Dispose();
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

i like to know how could i construct EF linq based query which will fetch data from multiple table but there is no relation between two table. so we can not perform join.

so show me a example where EF will fetch data from student and product table without any join with one db round trip. is it possible which was possible by ado.net as per my above example.

```
 var query = from data in context.Student
                orderby data.name
                select data;


 var query = from data in context.Product
                orderby data.name
                select data;
```

when two above query will run then two database round trip will occur or one ?

i need to fetch data from two table called student and product with one db round trip just like my above EF linq query.

if possible then discuss with sample code. thanks

Comment: None!!!  The query doesn't execute until you use the variable query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported out of the box, but there exists a "future queries" package that enables this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Plus.QueryFuture.EF6/

Comment: can u add a example of fetching data from 2 table using QueryFuture.EF6 plug-in. i checked their site but found no similar example.

Comment: There are examples at https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Plus/wiki/EF-Query-Future-%7C-Entity-Framework-Combine-and-Execute-Multiple-SQL-Command

Comment: are you talking about this routine `
var ctx = new EntitiesContext();

var futureCountries = ctx.Countries.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();
var futureStates = ctx.States.Where(x => x.IsActive).Future();

var countries = futureCountries.ToList();

var states = futureStates.ToList();`

Comment: see there is two separate ToList() like `futureCountries.ToList() and futureStates.ToList() and `...i guess two db round trip will occur. please tell me what will happen?

Comment: the db round trip for both queries will occur on the first ToList()

Comment: if futureCountries.ToList() will execute both then what this line will do futureStates.ToList() ?